# How to delete old packages from repository?

Tags: linux, repository, centos

I have a FTP server which I use for Linux repository for RPM packages. I need to delete old packages without doing it manually. Is there a script which can delete old packages based on package version?

Best wishes

Comment: Do you mean via ftp or can you also do it on the server directly. If so, it comes down to a script that can check versions, which might be not that trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run on the server side:

Depending on your favorite programming language, you can compare rpm versions with Perl or Python.

You can gather some ideas here:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch17s03s06.html and
http://metacpan.org/pod/RPM2 (Perl, package RPM2; provides a <=> operator for comparing versions) 
other CPAN modules: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=RPM&mode=all

[Compare RPM Packages using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380240/compare-rpm-packages-using-python) https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html http://www.sharms.org/blog/2009/05/python-rpm/ (Python, package rpm)

If you can't run on the server side, things become a little hairy, because all the naming/versioning schemes are difficult to tell apart.

Comment: Yes, I have root privileges on the server